# MS Access: Disable indexes in VBA?

Tags: ms-access, vba

Is it possible to disable indexes on Access tables during an import and then re-enable them? Something like:

```
  DisableIndexes(myTableName);
  do_a_large_import();
  EnableIndexes(myTableName);
```

Thanks, Peter

Answer (score 1):

You can use DAO or SQL to delete an index if it is not used by a relation.

You can later recreate it, given that the data will allow you.

Comment: Ok, so there is no "easy way". I have to delete every index in every table I use in my import and then recrate every one of these indexes...

Comment: Don't know about "easy", but not difficult. Problem is that you will be touching the basics of your database so there are many things to take care of.